# "shasum check failed" Error while installing Phonegap

Tags: macos, node.js, cordova, npm

I have problem while installing PhoneGap on my Mac OS machine using:

```
sudo npm install -g phonegap
```

Error message:

```
npm ERR! Error: shasum check failed for /Users/MYUSER/tmp/npm-33966-l4NZ7A8D/1387281663617-0.9133979633916169/tmp.tgz
npm ERR! Expected: dee5a33ff04d7217194dc1ad1342e3a441761942
npm ERR! Actual:   ab7d89ca1f31db14db047d01222dd968649cfb50
npm ERR!     at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/sha/index.js:38:8
npm ERR!     at ReadStream.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/sha/index.js:85:7)
npm ERR!     at ReadStream.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:120:20)
npm ERR!     at _stream_readable.js:896:16
npm ERR!     at process._tickCallback (node.js:599:11)
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this *entire* log,
npm ERR! including the npm and node versions, at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>

npm ERR! System Darwin 13.0.0
npm ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "phonegap"
npm ERR! cwd /Users/HummusawY
npm ERR! node -v v0.11.10-pre
npm ERR! npm -v 1.3.17
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/MYUSER/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
sudo npm install https://registry.npmjs.org/npm/-/npm-1.3.19.tgz
```

then

```
sudo npm install -g phonegap
```

The problem on my checksum was caused by https://registry.npmjs.org/npm/-/npm-1.3.19.tgz

Comment: this solution is much better than mine. You won;t need to downgrade node version

Answer (score 2):

## Try this first

"npm set registry https://registry.npmjs.org/"

## if failed then try to use the npm mirror:

"npm set registry http://ec2-46-137-149-160.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com"

## then use it normally:

npm install express

Answer (score 0):

You can downgrade Node.js to version 0.10.19 to solve the issue

Answer (score 0):

try:   npm install https://registry.npmjs.org/npm/-/npm-1.3.21.tgz

change from "19" to 21